# How to Delete Image from Firebase cloud Storage - REACT

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, firebase-storage

I have the following structure in my `Storage`, Post/ID/image.jpg . Post and ID are folders that can be found easily but ID may contain multiple images. How could I possibly delete all of them ?
Inside my code, I have a function that should delete Posts inside `firestore database` and delete the images reference from the `firebase storage`

The error thrown is :

> TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '_throwIfRoot')

Delete Function

```
const DeletePost = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const querySnapshot = await getDocs(collection(db, `${category}Posts`));
    querySnapshot.forEach((docx) => {
        if (post.AdTitle === docx.data().AdTitle) {
            try {
                deleteObject(ref(storage, `${category}Posts`, docx.id).child);
                deleteDoc(doc(db, `${category}Posts`, docx.id));
            } catch (error) {
                console.log("error in delete image, " + error);
            }
            // router.reload();
        }
    });
};
```

**EDIT**

[image: The post folder]
[image: the images to be deleted]
[image: Content of Docx.id]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following this [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/web/list-files) I finally came up with a working solution and here's the updated code.

```
try {
    const listRef = ref(storage, `${category}Posts/${docx.id}/`);
    listAll(listRef)
      .then((res) => {
        res.items.forEach((itemRef) => {
          setValues((prevState) => [...prevState, itemRef]);
        });
        if (values !== "") {
          console.log("attempting");
          values?.map((value) =>
            deleteObject(
              ref(storage, `${category}Posts/${docx.id}/${value.name}`)
            ).then(() => {
              console.log("storage success");
            })
          );

          deleteDoc(doc(db, `${category}Posts`, docx.id)).then(() => {
            console.log("doc success");
            router.reload();
          });
        }
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log("error : " + error);
      })
```

Answer (score 1):

There isn't any `child` property on a [StorageReference](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/storage.storagereference). Try removing it as shown below:

```
deleteObject(ref(storage, `${category}Posts`, docx.id + ".ext")) // .child);

// Make sure you add the file extension at the end
```

Also both `deleteObject()` and `deleteDoc` return a promise, so do checkout: [Using async/await with a forEach loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37576685/using-async-await-with-a-foreach-loop)

Comment: I first tried without child but I get the following error : `FirebaseError: Firebase Storage: Object 'ElectroniquePosts' does not exist. (storage/object-not-found)`

Comment: @Laspeed can you share a screenshot of file which you are trying to delete (make sure the path is visible)? And also `console.log(docx.id)` and share the output?

Comment: Please do check the edit @Dharmaraj

Comment: @Laspeed you do need to add file extension in the ref. Check my updated answer

Comment: Still getting : Firebase Storage: Object 'ElectroniquePosts' does not exist. (storage/object-not-found)

Comment: @Laspeed are you sure you had collection extension added to the end?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/240888/discussion-between-laspeed-and-dharmaraj).

Comment: Yes I copied and paste your answer

Comment: @Laspeed I mean you should replace `.ext` with `.png` if your file is PNG.

Comment: I accept multiple type of images so in my ID folder there are png and jpg etc specifying a single type may give a partial result but I still get that weird error 'ElectroniquePosts' doesn't exist. This is really confusing me to the max